# Prove a space is not finite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I want to prove that the linear space of all continuous functions from $ \mathbb{R} $ to $ \mathbb{R} $ is not finite-dimensional. Can you verify my proof?

Define $ A = \{f \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} \mid f \text{ is continuous} \}, V = (A, +, \cdot) $, and suppose $ A $ is finite-dimensional. Therefore, there exists $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ dimV = n \Rightarrow \forall B \subseteq A(\left|B\right| > n \Rightarrow B \text{ is lin. dependent})$. Choose $ B = \{1, x, x^2, x^3, ...\}$ which is lin. independent. However, $ |B| > n $ - contradiction.

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct

Comment: How do you argue that the $x^k$ are linearly independent?

Comment: Rather than appeal to the infinite set, I think its cleaner to appeal to the finite set $\{1,x,x^2,...,x^n\}$, which is of size $n+1>n$.

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe also show why exactly $\{1,x,x^2,...,\}$ are linearly independent, but the proof works.